# Fit image into div after rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, css

```
<div id="homePage"
        style="position: relative; margin: 0px; width: 320px; height: 420px;">
        <img id="userImg" src="images/5.jpg" width="100%"
            height="100%" onclick="imageClick()"
            style=" z-index: -1; margin: 0px;   "/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#userImg').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');

});

</script>
```

the image is fitting into div before Rotation, after rotation it is going out of boundaries, How can i fit the rotated image to DIV dimensions.

**Before rotate**

[image]

**After rotate**

[image]

Thanks,,

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Get the width and the height of the picture and change the dimensions after you rotated it.

```
var w= $('#homePage').width();
var h= $('#homePage').height();
console.log(w);
console.log(h);
$('#userImg').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
$('#homePage').height(h);
$('#homePage').width(w);
```

​